# How should I map model beans to view model beans in Spring MVC?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, viewmodel

In my Spring MVC application we have *form* objects that are mapped to by the `<form:form` tag in JSP.  These objects are separate from my regular model beans, and really form a sort of *view model*.  The difficulty with these objects is the mapping between these objects and the actual model beans expected by the service objects.  Currently we have manually written code mapping forms to beans and vice versa in the controllers.  This is less than optimal because of the amount of extra code it requires.  The other options we've considered are.

- Write a mapping class.  This still requires manually writing the code, but at least it's not in the controller.

  - Automatically generate the mapping class.  Presumably this would require manually generating and updating some sort of mapping file.
- Name the properties in beans and the forms the same and use Spring's [`BeanUtils.copyProperties`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to move them back and forth.  This seems bad because it is not an obvious link would cause strange run-time behavior if it wasn't kept consistent.
- Write the form object as a *facade* that keeps a bean internally and updates it.

What is the best method for the long term health of the project of performing this action?

Comment: Not sure if this belonged here or Programmers.  Feel free to move if appropriate.

Comment: Its an interesting question, that I'd be keen to see some view points on.  I have to admit that I don't often have this problem, as my form-backing beans are passed directly to my service. I tend to be more pragmatic and I don't always follow N-tier architecture best practices... but I think a lot of the benefits are over sold.

Comment: I wish there were more answers to this question. Your approach looks copmletely correct to me, but the mapping between model and viewmodel is tedious. Will look in to Dozer as ayengin suggested. How did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use   [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) framework for mapping domain objects and view object to each others .Only problem  you will have to still create view class manually.You can also automate this with code generation.